# Bootstrap div with responsive button at the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

been having an issue in bootstrap on how to have an input group like div with some contents inside and a responsive button at the right side. I want the button always at the right side which is also responsive. I tried with my code below but seems this isn't the right one. Please see demo below.

```css
.btn-custom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  top: -9px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
          <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">Go!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I wan't something like below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text Field" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" id="basic-addon2">Go</a>
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I want the button to be like the bootstrap's input-group with button to the right

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: Please see my sample above. I want the button to be like on the input-group-addon in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `pull-right`?

```
<div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
   <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-custom">Go!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to have a button like bootstrap's input-group with button to the right.